# Simple script to log Remote Desktop Connections

Tags: windows, vbscript, scripting, vb6, remote-desktop

I am trying to make a simple small script in vbscript which would run in background and log if someone have connected remotely to computer and when he left.

I made this so far and it works if I run the script manually but I want it to loop in background and write details to log.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set myLog = objFSO.OpenTextFile("rdcmonitor.log",2, True)
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
lastses="CONSOLE"
While True
    WScript.Sleep(1000)
    strSessionName = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SessionName%")
    if lastses <> Ucase(strSessionName) then
        lastses = Ucase(strSessionName)
        myLog.WriteLine vbLongDate & " __ session change (" & lastses & ")"
    End If
Wend
```

I want to make it work in vbscript.

Any ideas? Does it take "%SessionName%" only when starting script? Or it is somehow binded to who run it.

**EDIT:**

Tried also this way as @AlexK. suggested... But I cant seem to get to those log events however if I look manually to log events I see them.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set myLog = objFSO.OpenTextFile("temp.log",2, True)

strComputer = "."
'Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Security)}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
'Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE LogFile='Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager' ")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent")
'Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent Where Logfile = 'Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational'") 
myLog.WriteLine "."
For Each objEvent in colItems
    If objEvent.EventCode = 21 Then       
        myLog.WriteLine "************" 
        myLog.WriteLine "should be..." 
    End If
Next

msgbox("done")
```

Comment: SessionName will be the name of the session that originally launched the script.  The Event Viewer's Security log is the place to look for things like this.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. I will try check how to read from Event Log to vbscript or you know some sources?